# use keyboard arrow keys to navigate through the quickfix tag occurences in vim

Tags: vim

currently when i hit C-] under a keyword, sometimes i have many occurences, but i must enter the number of the tag occurence to go to its implementation, like this:

```
1 F   f    my_function  path/to/first/occurrence.c
               my_function(void)
2 F   f    my_function  path/to/second/occurrence.c
               my_function(void)
Type number and <Enter> (q or empty cancels):
```

i want to display the list and to navigate through its elements using keyboard arrays, should i use something like errorformat, or there is an other simple solution

i want to have:

```
1. my_function(void) : path/to/first/occurrence.c
2. my_function(void) : path/to/second/occurrence.c
```

Comment: What is keyboard array? Do you mean you want occurrences to be listed in quickfix?

Answer (score 3):

The output you provided is something that is produced by `:tselect` command, and this is not quickfix.

To list occurrences in quickfix, use `:ltag` command, then open the list with `:lopen`:

```
:ltag <some-keyword>
:lopen
```

If you want to activate quickfix entry with arrow keys:

```
autocmd! FileType qf autocmd! CursorMoved <buffer> :execute("norm! \<CR>\<C-W>w")
```

Comment: can you detail the solution please? :ltag opens also a tselect for me.

Comment: You need to provide an argument to `:ltag`, see `:help :ltag`. I updated the answer